# Practicing guitar for 10 minutes on every 50 minutes work cycle

Tags: practice

I was lucky to bring my guitar at work. I work 8 hours a day, work for 50 minutes,
and walk around for 10 minutes break. 
Right now, I'm using the 10 minutes break to practice guitar standing. Does this kind of practice work? Practice for 10 minutes then another after 50 minutes of work?

Comment: Lucky you!  I wish I could play my axe at work (for any time period at all).

Comment: Seriously, that's an awesome job that allows you to bring your guitar to practice.

Comment: It is a very good way to practice.

Comment: Where do you work :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's a great way to practise. You haven't got time for boredom or tedium to set in. In 10 minutes, as long as the guitar is in tune and you can just get on with it with no interruptions,and you have little tasks to complete in the given time,it's got to work.Longer sessions are hopefully available at some point in the week, but short practices usually work well. I say usually, as not everyone can pick up the guitar and get straight on with playing. It might take 5 mins to shake off what they did last, and another 2 or 3 to focus on the new task. For them it won't work - 2 or 3 mins to practise !  If you have several different mini-tasks it will be better than trying to, for example, learn a whole song in the 80 mins you give yourself. Scales for 10 mins. Chords for 10 mins, make up a new chord sequence for 10 mins, etc. If you are trying to learn a whole song, don't keep going back to the beginning at the next 10 mins. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations! You got a great job.

Practicing guitar isn't good if you doing that just twice a week or even once a week. It even better if you do that everyday in just 10 minutes. Or you can try something like "gym" do. Something like: Monday is for chords, tuesday is scales, wednesday I'm having fun, thursday is picking.

Perhaps, try to remember what you did with your guitar at the office (maybe scales while opening the net) in your home, and take practicing again at home for several minutes (10 minutes like what you do at the office is good).